# Encode/decode two strings into one string, and back to two

Tags: java, string, decode, encode

This is an interview question. I was thinking of a solution in java. This questions seems very simple, is there a catch here?

I was thinking of the following solution:

```
string1 + 1*hash(String1) + string2 + 2*hash(String2).
```

If I concat strings like this, then I can decode them as well easily into 2 separate strings.

Am I missing something in the question?

Comment: why not simply do it like the HTTP Authorization header requires username and passwords to be transmitted? `Basic Base64.enc(username + ":" + password)`? Decoding the base64 string of username and password will return `username:password` which you simple need to split by the `:` character

Comment: what if my string contains ":" ? i.e. username = joh:n password = do:e.

Comment: I'd simply use a character which is not contained in the allowed alphabet - simplyfies things pretty much. But what's the purpose of your 2nd hash-function? what do you need it for? what do you need the first hash-function for? how do you distinguish if a string has ended and the hash value of the former string begins? Hope you see what I'm trying to point at. fix to your problem could be: `len(string1)+string1+string2` as well

Answer (score 1):

Encode:

```
String encoded = new JsonArray().add(str1).add(str2).toString();
```

Decode:

```
JsonArray arr = JsonArray.readFrom(encoded);
String str1 = arr.get(0).asString();
String str2 = arr.get(1).asString();
```

Here I use [minimal-json](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json) lib, but it's pretty similar with any other JSON library as well.

Note that it's usually a bad idea to invent new formats of encoding the information into the string as you have plenty of existing ones (xml, json, yaml, etc.) which already solved all the possible issues like symbol escaping and exception handling.

Comment: readFrom is deprecated use this instead: JsonArray arr = Json.parse(encoded).asArray();

Answer (score 0):

To encode:

```
String encoded = ""+str1.length()+"/"+str1+str2;
```

To decode:

```
String[] temp = encoded.split("/", 2);
int length1 = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
String str1 = temp[1].substring(0, length1);
String str2 = temp[1].substring(length1);
```

Explanation:
The encoded string is in the form `"<number>/<str1><str2>"`. When you call `split(regex, limit)` the size of the resulting array will be at most `limit`, considering only the first matches of `regex`. Thus even if your strings contain the character `/` you can be sure that the resulting array will be `{"<number>", "<str1><str2>"}`.
the `substring(begin, end)` return a string starting at `begin` *inclusive* and ending at `end` *exclusive*, giving you a resulting substring of `end-begin` length. Since you are calling it with values`(0, str1.length())` what you get is exactly `str1`. The last call will return a substring from `str1.length()`, which is also the index of the first character of `str2`, to the end of the string (which is the end of `str2`).
Reference: [String javadoc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the length of the first string.

```
// encode
String concat = string1 + string2;

// decode
String str1 = concat.substring( 0, string1.length() );
String str2 = concat.substring( string1.length(), concat.length() );
```

Another way is to use a delimiter. But the delimiter character should not be included in any of the strings to be joined.

```
// encode
String concat = "hello" + "`" + "world!";

// decode
String[] decoded = concat.split("`");
String str1 = decoded[0];
String str2 = decoded[1];
```